# Misprint or misunderstanding?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, mistranslation

I tried to translate text:

> Offer Declined - Candidate staying at his current job.
>
> Recruiter - Why? This is a great offer. Did you accept a counter offer?
>
> Candidate - NO counter offer. The hiring experience was terrible and lengthy - 6 weeks.
>
> The environment is stale, the team was not welcoming, 4 rounds of interviews (2 phone and 2 in-person) the job description was not anywhere close to what I interviewed for and there is no flexibility or room to advance.
>
> Recruiter - The current offer offers 10K more
>
> Candidate - If you read through the reasons why I declined the offer you'll see that money is not that important.
>
> Employers must realize and acknowledge that the hiring process is broken and flawed.
>   Post jobs that make sense. 
>   Treat candidates like Talent, not job seekers. 
>   Cut your hiring process by 50% or 60%. 
>   Be welcoming, informative and supportive throughout the hiring process. Make us feel welcomed, wanted and appreciated. Not strangers asked why are you here?
>
> **No appreciation for our time and interest. No urgency**
>
> I said it before and will say it again. To all the EMPLOYERS, RECRUITERS and MANAGERS out there 
>   "Attracting talent is a talent. You must have the talent to attract talent" Mike Daly

Well, I clearly got everything except bold line.

He says that employers dont appreciate candidates time and interest in context of advice to employers?
and "no urgency" in the same time...

I believe that I miss something here, could you help me?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that it should sounds like:  
`Make us feel welcomed, wanted and appreciated`.  
`Not strangers asked:"why are you here?" with no appreciation for our time and interest.`      
`No urgency. `    
At least it will be pretty close to whole message of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that poor punctuation might be responsible, and the intention might have been “No appreciation for our time and interest, no urgency.”
A desire for shared sense of urgency by both parties.

Comment: You have not adequately explained this answer, and it's not clear what the comma has to do with that interpretation of the passage. The words "no urgency" by themselves _might_ signify that one or both parties needs a greater sense of urgency, but they seem equally likely to signify this as a standalone sentence fragment (preceded by a full stop) and perhaps even more unlikely to signify this when following a comma. (A comma could signal causation: "My lack of urgency is due to your lack of appreciation.")